# Emulating HTTP POST via httpclient 3.x for multi options

Tags: java, http, post, httpclient

I want to emulate a HTTP POST using application/x-www-form-urlencoded encoding
to send a option group that allows multiple selections.

```
<select name="groups" multiple="multiple" size="4">
    <option value="2">Administration</option>
    <option value="1">General</option>
</select>
```

Does adding 2 NameValuePairs (NVP) with the same name work ? My serverside log shows that only the first NVP was received.

e.g

```
PostMethod method = ...;
NameValuePair[] nvpairs = {
    new NameValuePair( "groups", "2" );
    new NameValuePair( "groups", "1" );
};
method.addParameter( nvpairs );
```

Only the groups=1 parameter was received. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More likely is that your server code is calling `ServletRequest.getParameter()` rather than `getParameterValues()`.

But the best way to verify is use an HTTP proxy such as [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to look at the actual request.

---

Edit: the correct `HttpClient` method is `addParameters()`, not `addParameter()` -- your code shows the latter, but I don't believe it would compile so am assuming you copied incorrectly.